# GitHub action exporter for monitoring with prometheus and grafana

Tags: github, github-actions, prometheus, grafana, open-telemetry

Do we have any anything similar to https://github.com/mvisonneau/gitlab-ci-pipelines-exporter/blob/main/README.md for `GitHub Actions` exporter and grafana dashboard for monitoring purpose?

Comment: I will just leave it here: [help/on-topic].